# partial scalar measurement invariance

Tags: measurement, confirmatory-factor, partial-effect, invariance

I have performed a measurement invariance analysis in R using SemTools, to assess the five factor structure of a questionnaire across 3 age groups. The latent variables have 5 indicators (5 items). I have used the "MLM" estimation method. Configural and metric invariance can be confirmed, however, scalar invariance cannot be confirmed based on an increase in CFI of >.01. When looking at the modification indices (lavTestScore(scores, cumulative = TRUE) followed by parTable(scores)) I found out which intercepts to free across agegroups to establish partial scalar invariance. However, when I look at the intercept estimates in the three age groups individually, the intercepts to be freed according to the MI are not the ones with the biggest difference in intercept values in the model fit for the individual age groups (standardised or non-standardised). How can this discrepancy be explained? Freeing these intercepts indicated by the MI does increase model fit.